# How to read hidden attributes from a page loaded in SWT Browser

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

I am working on an Eclipse plugin which loads a URL in the SWT browser. This page rendered in the browser has hidden html attributes. The requirement is to read the values of the hidden attributes.

```java
Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
browser.setUrl("www.<my_url>.com");
```

I tried to execute a query on the DOM using the statusTextListener

```java
browser.addStatusTextListener(new StatusTextListener() {
  public void changed(StatusTextEvent event) {
    browser.setData("query", event.text);
  }
});
browser.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {

  public void completed(ProgressEvent event) {
    boolean result = browser
        .execute("window.status=document.getElementById('main').childNodes[0].nodeValue;");
    if (!result) {
      /* Script may fail or may not be supported on certain platforms. */
      System.out.println("Script was not executed.");
      return;
    }
    String value = (String) browser.getData("query");
    System.out.println("Node value: " + value);
  }
});
```

However this does not seem to work. It works well if I try to load HTML text in the browser instead of the URL.
Any idea how to read DOM elements from the SWT browser after the page load is complete?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Browser::evaluate` to execute Javascript in the context of the document and return the result to the caller.

To obtain the value of the first child of the `main` element in your example, start like this:

```java
String script = "<Javascript to return an array of hidden attribute names>";
Object result = browser.evaluate(script);
```

The supported result types, however, are limited to `string`, `number`, and `boolean` - and arrays of these types. Javascript that evaluates to `null` or `undefined` will return `null`.

Hence, you will need to adjust your Javascript that queries the DOM to return a supported type.

Comment: I was able to get the value using the above solution.The value of the hidden field is populated async by means of ajax.Hence when the completed handler is called it may not always hold the value. Is there any way to keep a watch on the value change?

Comment: If you are able to 'inject' a listener into the page that gets notified when the Ajax request was made, you may have a look at [BrowserFunctions](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet307.java) to call back to the application.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this without making any changes to the target html? the target html is not under our scope

Comment: Then I recommend to stay away from hacks that make you dependant on the implementation details of sources you cannot control. That left aside, you may be able to use Browser::execute to register some sort of global fetch/XHR-request listener that gets notified whenever a request is made from this page. Not sure though if such a browser API exists.